# UIElements becomes inactive when RootViewController is set from SceneDelegate in iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, ios13

I am currently experiencing these issues in Xamarin.iOS update to iOS 13.1.
When I set the LoginController manually as the initial ViewController from Main.Storyboard everything works fine, but when I set LoginController as the rootViewController in the SceneDelegate.cs all UIElements will be inactive when my app loads up.

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
    [Export("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
    public void WillConnect(UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
    {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).

        //// Decide first screen
        UIWindowScene windowScene = new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions);

        var window = new UIWindow(windowScene);
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

        var registerController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController;
        this.SetWindow(window);


        window.RootViewController = registerController;
        window?.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        window.MakeKeyWindow();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a view controller as the root controller for anything will make your app un-navigable. a view controller is for controller managing a view unless you've developed said view controller to manage views like a navigation controller and from the looks of it, that's not what you're doing. navigation controllers manage view controllers. so make the root a navigation controller with the root of that navigation controller the "LoginViewController" and see what happens. also, stop using story boards, you'll be in a world of hurt if/when you app reaches more than 100 view controllers. learn to handle this programmatically and you'll soon learn how this whole navigation thing works and interacts with controllers and views.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is **customed window** not be assigned to `this.Window` . Modifying code as follow :

```
[Export("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
public void WillConnect(UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).

    //// Decide first screen
    UIWindowScene windowScene = new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions);

    //var window = new UIWindow(windowScene);
    this.Window = new UIWindow(windowScene); 
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

    var registerController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController;
    //this.SetWindow(window);


    this.Window.RootViewController = registerController;
    this.Window?.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    this.Window.MakeKeyWindow();

}
```

Then it can work.

=================================Update====================================

If not working , there are two ways to find the reason:

**One way** is to make sure that follow code `registerController` is not null .

```
var registerController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController;
```

You need to check whether **StoryBoard ID** in **StoryBoard** match with **LoginViewController** .
[image]

**Another way**, you can create a UIViewController Class not inside StoryBoard to check it .
[image]

```
 this.Window.RootViewController = new NewCreatedViewController();
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. Though it didnt really resolve the issue. But after hours of reasearch i discovered that there is Bug in the new iOS 13.1 simulators that freezes UItextFields. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122972

Comment: @UchennaNnodim Okey , if code not working . You can have a try with `ViewController` not inside `StoryBoard` to check whether can show . I will update the answer.